# scanf in C- Spaces cause deletion

Tags: c, scanf

I wrote this code to find the roots of a quadratic equation.It seems to work unless I put a space before the scanning part. (for example in the input I write: `a=1,b=2, c=1`). In that case it just deletes the variable. (In the example I gave `c` would be deleted from the input and as such the answers I receive are 0,-2 instead of -1.).  The code works if I put the space somewhere else (`a  =1,b= 2,c=1`).

How can I fix this problem?

```
int main()
{
    double root1 = 0, root2 = 0;
    double a = 0., b = 0., c = 0.;
    printf("Enter a polynomial:\n");
    scanf("a=%lf,b=%lf,c=%lf", &a, &b, &c);

    {
        if (a == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if ((b * b - 4 * a * c) == 0)
        {
            root1 = -b / 2 * a;
            printf("root is %f", root1);
        }
        else if ((b * b - 4 * a * c) < 0)
        {
            printf("There are no roots");
        }
        else {
            root1 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2* a;
            root2 = (-b - sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2* a;
            printf("Roots are %f,%f", root1, root2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just input 1,2,1 then enter

Comment: Because the leading space is not a part of your format string.

Comment: Forget those silly commas,and stringent input specs, just don't type any. `printf("Enter a polynomial a b c:\n"); scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &a, &b, &c);` and then enter `1 2 1` or separated by `newline`.

Comment: Nit: `"There are no roots"` --> `"There are no real roots"`.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  It seems to be missing the `#include` statements for the header files: `stdio.h` and `math.h`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: exactly what part(s) of a polynomial are `a` `b` `c`?  That detail should be included in the prompt to the user

Comment: in modern C, if the returned value is 0 then there is no need for the `return 0;` statement at the end of the program.  Note: in general there should be only one exit point from a function.  A slight rearrangement of the logic would eliminate  that first return statement

Comment: the streams `stdout` and `stderr` are buffered.  In general, this means that the contents of the buffer will not be displayed until either: 1) the buffer gets full 2) a '\n' is output 3) the function: `fflush()` is called with the appropriate parameter. or 4) the program ends.  Strongly suggest ending each of the format strings in the calls to `printf()`  end with '\n',

Comment: when calling any of the scanf() family of functions, any characters in the format string must be in the input. in this case, it is very unlikely that a= or b= or c= will be in the input. Suggest incorporating a prompt to the user that actually says what the code is expecting. For instance: "Enter the three floating point factors a b c that make a polynomial" 2) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. Suggest: if( 3 != scanf( "%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c) ) { // handle error and exit }

Answer (score 2):

Use a format the allows for space in unexpected places.  And check results.

```
//         v v    v v v    v v v
if (scanf(" a =%lf , b =%lf , c =%lf", &a, &b, &c) == 3) Oh_Happy_day();
```

A space is not *needed* before `"%lf"` as that specifier will scan through leading white-space.  Some like to be explicit

```
//             x         x         x Optional
if (scanf(" a = %lf , b = %lf , c = %lf", &a, &b, &c) == 3) Oh_Happy_day();
```

---

Still better to use `fgets()` to read a *line* and then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to fix this problem; this is actually a problem with the function scanf(); itself. Alternately, you can use fgets(); instead.
try replacing

```
double a=0.,b=0.,c=0.;
printf("Enter a polynomial:\n");
scanf("a=%lf,b=%lf,c=%lf",&a,&b,&c);
```

with

```
double a=0.0,b=0.0,c=0.0;
printf("Enter a polynomial:\n");
scanf(" %lf, %lf, %lf",&a,&b,&c);
```

Comment: Not so (that is, there are ways to fix this problem); the problem is in the way `scanf()` is being abused.

Answer (score 0):

Because the space is **not** part of the formatting string you used in scanf.

You should add the leading space in the formatting string:

```
scanf(" a=%lf, b=%lf, c=%lf", &a, &b, &c);
```

Comment: The format string is better now, but would reject input starting `a = 1.23`.  Maybe that's what's required, but `" a = %lf , b = %lf , c = %lf"` would be more flexible.  The spaces before the `%lf` are not needed to maintain the flexibility, but they make the format more symmetric.  You should test the result from `scanf()` too, to make sure that 3 values were converted successfully.  Of course, making people type the `a=1.23, b = 2.34, c= 3.45` notation is unpleasant, especially as they don't get the flexibility to type `b = 2.34, c = 3.45, a = 1.23` (which would justify the extra typing).